# StartsWith and array not working correctly with empty space

Tags: c#

```
_comboBoxItems array

    [0] = "01 01010304"
    [0] = "01 01230304"
    [0] = "01 01010784"
    [0] = "01 01135404"

typedSoFar = "010"

    if (_comboBoxItems[i].StartsWith(typedSoFar, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        match = _comboBoxItems[i];

        break;
    }
```

but if is never true. why? 010 is part of 01 01010304 for example. can be problem StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase?

Comment: It is part if you use `Contains()` not `StartsWith()`

Comment: sorry my mistake. I did not see this. Thank you again

Comment: Maybe it is not your fault. It is about how you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never true because none of your elements start with 010. StartsWith() only looks at the substring starting at index 0.

You should use String.Contains() instead.

Answer (score 1):

using startswith(), it will always match start of string-input. Use Contains() to search and match substring anywhere in the string-input

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want the `typedSoFar` to match the beginning of the string without the spaces then use this:

```
if (_comboBoxItems[i].StartsWith(typedSoFar.Trim())
{
    match = _comboBoxItems[i];
}
```

the above will match this `01 01010304` but not this `01 11010304`.

If you want the the `typedSoFar` to be a part of the string use this:

```
if (_comboBoxItems[i].Contains(typedSoFar)
{
    match = _comboBoxItems[i];
}
```

*In you case I don't see any purpose of using the `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`